# Push object and keys with multiple value to array in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array of words, and I want to search the words in text array , find them and check if next element or elements after word are numbers , push the number or numbers with word in new object and push object to new array. like this:

```
words = ['blue' , 'red' , 'yellow' , 'grin' , 'black' , 'white'];

text = ['xxx'  , 'yyy' , 'red' , 'zzz' , 'black' , 65 , 54 , 'white' , 'aaa' , 'yellow' , 50 , 'ppp'];


Output I want: 

[{'black' : [65 , 54] , 'yellow' : [50]}];
```

But my current code just returns the numbers after word and push them in new array:

```
words = ['blue' , 'red' , 'yellow' , 'grin' , 'black' , 'white'];

text = ['xxx'  , 'yyy' , 'red' , 'zzz' , 'black' , 65 , 54 , 'white' , 'aaa' , 'yellow' , 50, 'ppp'];

        const set = new Set(words);
        let result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if (set.has(text[i])) {
            while (typeof text[i + 1] == "number") {
              result.push(text[++i]);
            }
          }
        }

      console.log(result)

//output : [65 , 54 , 50]
```

So how can I push numbers with their keys to an array?

Comment: Because you push the number. If you want an object create one and push it

Comment: I don't know how to push object with current word key and number as value , i  tried but doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not the object creation and pushing to main array properly. You are checking whether the nodes from `text` is there in array `words`, if thats found you are pushing the numbers after that found word to an array correclty. But you should not push that to a plain array. instead you should push it to an object having the key that you found as the match, it should be declared as empty array initially. There after numbers after that needs to be pushed to this array.

Please find the working fiddle for same

```js
const words = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'grin', 'black', 'white'];
// const text = ['black'  , 50 , 'black' , 600 , 10 , 'black' , 40];
const text = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'red', 'zzz', 'black', 65, 54, 'white', 'aaa', 'yellow', 50, 'ppp'];
const set = new Set(words);
const finalResult = [];
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (set.has(text[i])) {
    const newObj = {};
    const key = text[i];
    const result = [];
    while (typeof text[i + 1] == "number") {
      result.push(text[++i]);
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      newObj[key] = result
      finalResult.push(newObj);
    }
  }
}
console.log(finalResult);
```

`Array.reduce` implementation of your requirement will be like this

```js
const words = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'grin', 'black', 'white'];
// const text = ['black'  , 50 , 'black' , 600 , 10 , 'black' , 40];
const text = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'red', 'zzz', 'black', 65, 54, 'white', 'aaa', 'yellow', 50, 'ppp'];
const modifiedText = text.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (typeof text[index] === "string" && typeof text[index + 1] === "number" && words.includes(curr)) {
    const newArr = [];
    let startIndex = index + 1;
    while (text[startIndex] && typeof text[startIndex] === "number") {
      newArr.push(text[startIndex]);
      startIndex++;
    }
    if(newArr.length) {
      acc.push({[curr] : newArr });
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(modifiedText);
```

Comment: your codes work, but not for duplicate words, for example if the text be this : `['black'  , 50 , 'black' , 600 , 10 , 'black' , 40]` just returns `{ black: [40 ] }` , I want all words and numbers, even if they are duplicates

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot it , so can we change it to this ?`[{black : [50]} , {black : [600 , 10]} , {black : [40] }]` because i need the keys

Comment: `[ {'black' : [65 , 54]} , {'yellow' : [50] } ];`

Comment: It is not a problem if we have multiple objects instead of one

Answer (score 2):

You still collect numbers in `result` array if you find a matching word. But you start with an empty array for every matching word.

You don't want to use the increment operator on `i` to go through `text`.

`res` is an `Object` in which you store matching words as keys and `result` arrays as values.

```js
words = ['blue' , 'red' , 'yellow' , 'grin' , 'black' , 'white'];

text = ['xxx'  , 'yyy' , 'red' , 'zzz' , 'black' , 65 , 54 , 'white' , 'aaa' , 'yellow' , 50, 'ppp'];

const set = new Set(words);
let res = {};
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (set.has(text[i])) {
    let result = [];
    let j = i;
    while (typeof text[j + 1] == "number") {
      result.push(text[++j]);
    }
    if(result.length > 0) res[text[i]] = result;
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: you code works but not for duplicate colors, for example if the text be this : `['black'  , 50 , 'black' , 600 , 10 , 'black' , 40]` just returns `{ black: [40 ] }`

Comment: I want all colors and numbers, even if they are duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You need to push an object containing the word as a key and the numbers you want.

Something like

```
words = ['blue' , 'red' , 'yellow' , 'grin' , 'black' , 'white'];

text = ['xxx'  , 'yyy' , 'red' , 'zzz' , 'black' , 65 , 54 , 'white' , 'aaa' , 'yellow' , 50, 'ppp'];

        const set = new Set(words);
        let result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if (set.has(text[i]) && typeof text[i + 1] == "number") {
            let key = text[i]
            let arr = []
            while (typeof text[i + 1] == "number") {
              arr.push(++i)
            }
            result.push({[key]: arr})
          }
        }

      console.log(result)
```

Comment: `let key = text[i]`  and `result.push({key: arr})`  doesn't work, 'key' is declared but its value is never read , and the when you push it to array returns this : `[ { key: [ 5, 6 ] }, { key: [ 10 ] } ]`

Comment: You are correct, corrected typo in the code.
Is it returning what you had in mind now?

Comment: Yes it returns what i want